# Laravel can't see existing vendor class after update

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, thephpleague

I am no longer able to send email from my Laravel app once I updated to v6.10, 6.11.  I have not changed any code, nor have I required or removed anything new from composer recently.  This appears to be potentially something with the new build of Laravel, as this exact code is functional and sending email on v6.7 and below.

**Error** msg:

> Class 'League\CommonMark\Environment' not found (View: /home/ww/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html/footer.blade.php)
>
> {"exception":"[object] (Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException(code:
>   0): Class 'League\CommonMark\Environment' not found (View:
>   /home/ww/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views/html/footer.blade.php)
>   at
>   /home/videocyp/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Markdown.php:103)

The line from my **footer** from *my published* vendor file that is causing the issue:

```
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}
```

Inside the *vendor* file **Markdown.php**

```
use League\CommonMark\Environment;

 class Markdown
 { 
    public static function parse($text)
    {
       $environment = Environment::createCommonMarkEnvironment();
       // etc...
 }
```

Looking at `League\CommonMark\Environment`, I find the class (as does my IDE):

```
final class Environment implements EnvironmentInterface, ConfigurableEnvironmentInterface { }
```

I'm beyond my level of understanding here as to why Laravel is unable to see one of its vendor classes.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan dump-autoload`?

Comment: Thanks - yes I have (composer).  No change.  I didn't say it, but I'm running php7.4 - not sure that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is the result of a significant (slightly breaking) change made to the Laravel build as of v6.10.

Due to a potential XSS vulnerability, it looks like they changed the root parser to League CommonMark.  This is causing other issues with existing email published templates due to excess white space being parsed differently in the new CommonMark parser.  Bugs are reported [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31092), [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31081), [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31065).

My particular problem was extremely strange, but it is being reported elsewhere in addition to those reported back to Laravel.  It was not consistent across my servers, but a complete rebuild (vagrant) solved the issue.

For the others with their previously published email templates showing raw HTML, a re-publish may resolve the issue if lucky and no changes were made to the templates.

Comment: For people experience this in Forge or other environments that might be using a queue worker - try restarting it to make it aware of code changes.

Comment: Hi @PeterTheLobster yes I'm experiencing this with queue worker. What do you mean by restarting? Do you mean restarting the queue worker because I did but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to regenerate the list of all classes that need to be included in your project.

```
php artisan clear-compiled -o
composer dump-autoload
```

If still not working, maybe try reinstalling the package.

```
composer require league/commonmark
```

What version of Laravel did you upgrade from? Laravel 6.7?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Karl.  I tried the above, but no joy.  I upgraded from 6.7, but these projects have been continuously uploaded since 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help Karl.  Turns out this is a change Laravel made to the framework that affects a whole lot more than my missing class thing.